# Get project map extent in standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How can I get the map extent defined in QGIS project in standalone python script? Not for a layer, but for the map canvas. Since it is a standalone script, I cannot use iface class and `QgsMapCanvas().extent()` only gives me `<QgsRectangle: 0 0, 0 0>`. Using QGIS 3.4.

Comment: As you've seen, a project has no extent, but it could have related layers and map canvases. In a standalone script, you should create any map canvas you need by yourself. So, depending on the use case, it could make more sense to calculate the combined extent of registered layers in the project.